# BeautifulSoup doesnt retrieve all data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to retrieve all comments from a reddit user using beautifulsoup. Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.reddit.com/user/IHateTheLetterF/"
client = ureq(url)

page_html = client.read()



pagesoup = soup(page_html, "html5lib")

comments = pagesoup.findAll("p",{"class":"_1qeIAgB0cPwnLhDF9XSiJM"})
```

This works if i try to retrieve some of the comments but for some reason it only retrieves 16 comments and the user clearly has more than 16 comments. I have tried using different parsers like lxml,html.parser and html5lib but they all only retrieve 16 comments. Weirdly enough the exact same code retrieved 22 comments yesterday. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the page uses dynamic javascript to load the comment contents. So you won't be able to accomplish it using `ureq`.

Instead you should use selenium with a webdriver to load all the comments before scraping.

You can try downloading ChromeDriver executable [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). And if you paste it in the same folder as your script you can run:

**Edit: using a custon scroller to force page to keep loading new comments**

```py
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# configure driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

url = "https://www.reddit.com/user/IHateTheLetterF/comments/"
driver.get(url)
scroll_pause_time = 3  # You can try with your own pause time.

screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")  # get screen height
i = 1

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  # scroll screen height
    i += 1  # times looped
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)  # wait content to load
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  # check current scroll height
    
    # Check your content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    comments = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "_1qeIAgB0cPwnLhDF9XSiJM"})
    print(len(comments))
    
    # Finish loops when you cant scroll anymore
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break
```

I let it run for some minutes and was getting more than 200 comments already.

Although this may work, I suggest you looking [propper APIs](https://github.com/JosephLai241/URS) for this.

Comment: Its certainly better than before but clearly the user has more than 60 comments?

Comment: Apparently reddit uses an infinnity scroll system. I'll edit the answer to create a custon scroller but you should check for [propper APIs](https://github.com/JosephLai241/URS)